# How can I add rows dynamically in datatable for SQL Server

Tags: c#, datatable

How to add rows into a datatable dynamically?

I created some columns with this code:

```
DataTable obj_dt_grdvw = new DataTable();
obj_dt_grdvw.Columns.Add("_Pur_Product_Id", typeof(string));
obj_dt_grdvw.Columns.Add("Product_pur_Name", typeof(string));
```

Now I tried to add a row of data but showing error "there is no row at 0"

```
obj_dt_grdvw.Rows[0]["_Pur_Product_Id"] ="12";
obj_dt_grdvw.Rows[0]["Product_pur_Name"] ="milk";
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create new datatable, it is empty - i.e. there is no rows. That's why you can't find row at index `0`. You should create and add rows manually.

Use [DataTable.NewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to create new row with same columns (i.e. same schema) as your datatable:

```
DataRow row = obj_dt_grdvw.NewRow(); // create new row
row["_Pur_Product_Id"] ="12"; // set field values
row["Product_pur_Name"] ="milk";
obj_dt_grdvw.Rows.Add(row); // add this new row to table rows
```

Comment: please see this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583546/how-to-add-data-to-data-table-and-show-in-grid-view-c-sharp