# How to add data to Datatable and show in grid view c#

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, datarow

I need to add data to datatable and show it in a gridview. After entering each item, gridview should update automatically.

```
        DataTable obj_dt_grdvw = new DataTable();
        DataRow obj_dt_row = obj_dt_grdvw.NewRow();


        obj_dt_grdvw.Columns.Add("_Pur_Product_Id", typeof(string));
        obj_dt_grdvw.Columns.Add("Product_pur_Name", typeof(string));


        obj_dt_row["_Pur_Product_Id"] = _Pur_Product_Id;
        obj_dt_row["Product_pur_Name"] = Product_pur_Name;

        obj_dt_grdvw.Rows.Add(obj_dt_row);
        return obj_dt_grdvw;
```

After returning `obj_dt_grdvw`, all the data gets erased automatically from  datatable. I would like to  delete the data manually.

Comment: It's not clear what problem you have. Just assign this DataTable (which have one row) to your GridView

Comment: What is the source of your data in the grid?

Comment: Continued from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583145/how-can-i-add-rows-dynamically-in-datatable-for-sql-server